# Why is Ant Design throwing a Server Error when trying to use date-fns?

Tags: typescript, next.js, antd, date-fns

After replacing Moment.js with date-fns using [this guide](https://ant.design/docs/react/replace-moment) from the antd documentation I get the next server error:

[Screenshot of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGUzh.jpg)

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I've tried things like adding `'type': 'module'` to the package.json and putting `'module': 'commonjs'` in tsconfig.json and many other things but none seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. The solution was to replace `'antd/es/...'` with `'antd/lib/...'` in the imports provided in the documentation and the error was gone.

Your DatePicker.tsx should look like this

```
import dateFnsGenerateConfig from 'rc-picker/lib/generate/dateFns';
import generatePicker from 'antd/lib/date-picker/generatePicker';
import 'antd/lib/date-picker/style/index';

const DatePicker = generatePicker<Date>(dateFnsGenerateConfig);

export default DatePicker;
```

Comment: So much time spent modifying the package.json to try to fix this error... and it came down to competing import sources? Ug. But seriously, though, thanks for ending this misery for me!